# Know which keyboard is shown

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

I am building an app with a `UITextField` showing the decimal keyboard when the user taps it.

I want to add a "done" button myself above the keyboard so I wanted to use this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

It works perfectly to detect when the keyboard is going up but my problem is that I have other text fields on the same `UIView` but I don't want to add this "done" button on them.

Is there a way to detect if it is the decimal keyboard which is shown or the regular one?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You should be creating and setting the `inputAccessoryView` property of the particular text field to accomplish this. Read the Apple docs on [Input Views and Input Accessory Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html). Also, be aware that the iPad does not have a numeric keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use inputAccessoryView property of textfied

```
txtfld.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
txtfld.inputAccessoryView=[self toolBarForKeyboardAccessory];
```

and then

```
-(UIToolbar *)toolBarForKeyboardAccessory
{
 UIToolbar *keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
 keyboardToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

UIBarButtonItem* flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];


UIBarButtonItem* cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonClicked:)];
 CGRect rect = CGRectMake(1, 5.0, 250, 30);
KeyboardTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
KeyboardTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
KeyboardTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
KeyboardTextField.delegate = self;

 UIBarButtonItem *textFieldItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:KeyboardTextField] ;

[keyboardToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: flexSpace,textFieldItem,flexSpace, cancelButton,flexSpace, nil] animated:NO];

return keyboardToolbar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `if-statement` to check which UITextField's keyboard is on the screen:

```
 if ([yourTextField isFirstResponder])
 {
       //Add done button
 }
```